# python uni-code server error while passing non English words

Tags: python, google-app-engine, unicode, encode, urllib

I build a customized search web page using some other search engine. like.

For client side am encode the search terms and send to the my server using

http://xxx.appspot.com/search?q=encodeUIComponent(qTerms)

At server side(appengine - python) am decoding the text using urllib

like `qTerms= urllib.unquote_plus(qTerms)`

and again i encoded the sterms.
using `qTerms= urllib.quote_plus(qTerms)`

now i send qTermsto the another server from my server and i get xml response.

Above designs works well for pure engilsh words when i pass the non english words its givin error like below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/webapp/_webapp25.py",          line 701, in __call__
    handler.get(*groups)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~searchepic/1.353951740301902288/search.py", line 124, in get
    qTerms = urllib.quote_plus(qTerms)
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_dist/lib/python2.5/urllib.py", line 1222, in quote_plus
    return quote(s, safe)
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_dist/lib/python2.5/urllib.py", line 1214, in quote
    res = map(safe_map.__getitem__, s)
KeyError: u'\u0c15'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass quote() ASCII (str) string instead of unicode string.
You porbbley need to call `term.encode('utf8')` and pass the result to quote()

Comment: ANSI? Have I slipped into a time-warp to 1982?